# Ellipsize is not working if android:inputType="textCapSentences" used in textview

Tags: android

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_search_string"
            android:text="sdsdf kjnknlkn kjnlknln lknlnln lknlsnln lkjnlkjj hbhbhb hbhbh "
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="#333"
            android:textSize="@dimen/txt_18sp"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dimen_5dp"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/dimen_5dp"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"/>
```

in the above text view if i remove "inputType" then ellipsize is working where as if i add "inputType" ellipsize isn't working.

i need both ellipsize and inputType="textCapSentences" in the same textview

Answer (score 1):

**[android:ellipsize](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:ellipsize)**

> If set, causes words that are longer than the view is wide to be
>   ellipsized instead of broken in the middle. You will often also want
>   to set scrollHorizontally or singleLine as well so that the text as a
>   whole is also constrained to a single line instead of still allowed to
>   be broken onto multiple lines.

**Do**

```
android:inputType="text"
```

**Do not**

```
android:inputType="textCapSentences"
```

Comment: i need the first letter of all words in the sentence in capital, that is why i have used "textCapSentences"